# Trying to give Full Permissions to s3 Log Delivery Group using the aws-cdk

Tags: boto3, aws-cdk

I am currently using the aws-cdk to create a central logging bucket that all existing s3 buckets will log to. Everything is working when I give the 's3LogDeliveryGroup' List Objects, Write Objects, Read-Bucket-Permissions, and Write Bucket Permissions manually. However I am using the aws-cdk and need to do this programmatically so I can deploy this to any account.
Here is my code:

```
const s3PublicAccessLambda = new lambda.Function(this, 's3PublicAccessLambda',{
        runtime: lambda.Runtime.PYTHON_3_6,
        handler: 's3PublicAccess.handler',
        role:s3LoggingLambdaRole,
        code: lambda.Code.fromAsset(path.join(__dirname, '../lambda')),
        timeout: cdk.Duration.seconds(300) 

      });

      const centralLoggingBucket = new s3.Bucket(this, 'centralLoggingBucket', {
        accessControl:s3.BucketAccessControl.BUCKET_OWNER_FULL_CONTROL

      });
      centralLoggingBucket.grantReadWrite(s3LoggingLambdaRole);
  
      }
    }
```

No errors occur when running this code, however the buckets just won't log unless I manually give the permissions. I know I need to specify it somewhere near where I specified the 'accessControl' parameter I just don't know exactly where. Thank you!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're looking for a way to provide the S3 bucket access policies to the role `s3LoggingLambdaRole` that is assumed by the lambda function, you can try attaching an inline policy like so:

```
s3LoggingLambdaRole.attachInlinePolicy(
    new Policy(this, 'yourPolicy', {
        policyName: 'yourPolicyName',
            statements: [
                new PolicyStatement({
                    actions: ['s3:ListObjects', 's3:WriteObjects'],
                    resources: [`arn:aws:s3:::`, `arn:aws:s3:::*`, 'arn:aws:s3:::*/*'],
                }),
            ],
        }),
    );
```

Also, remember that if you provided your own custom IAM role, it is not automatically granted permission to execute the lambda so you might have to add the following managed policy as well.

```
s3LoggingLambdaRole.addManagedPolicy(ManagedPolicy.fromAwsManagedPolicyName("service-role/AWSLambdaBasicExecutionRole"));
s3LoggingLambdaRole.addManagedPolicy(ManagedPolicy.fromAwsManagedPolicyName("service-role/AWSLambdaVPCAccessExecutionRole")); // only required if your function lives in a VPC
```